# Cutting a square out of the center of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

There may already be answers for what I need to know, however, I cannot seem to make work what answers I do find.  So, I will ask anyways.  I have an image that is floral in design.  I have it saved as both a png and as a jpeg.  What I am wanting to do with it is make it into a picture frame by cutting out the center of it, leaving about an inch or so all around the edge.  I want the hole I cut out to be transparent so that I can either slide another pic underneath it or put it over the top of another pic.  When I am done, I will save it as a png.  I can use Adobe Illustrator, or Photoshop.  I really need some help please.

Comment: Just one thing to add, find out about [how to use layer masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) in Photoshop. This is real basic stuff you should learn, and that you can apply to help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a mask in this situation:

1. create a square shape with the rectangle tool (use the shift key to keep the proportions of a square)
2. center it on your image
3. create a mask linked to the image layer
4. ctrl+click on the rectangle layer thumbnail to make a selection out of it
5. click on the mask layer and press ctrl+i

then you can save it as a png.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!!! That's one good way of doing it (non-destructive) pretty good first answer.